# Why is my text blurry when I transfer it from Illustrator to InDesign?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I know that we aren't supposed to use Illustrator for text, but I needed to use the Type on a Path feature and that's why I did it.

[image: Here is text in Illustrator.]

Above is the text in Illustator. When I export the text from Illustrator to InDesign, the text becomes blurry.

[image]

I'm assuming because it becomes an image file when it goes into InDesign.

Thus, I was wondering if there was a way to increase the image quality or directly copy the text boxes from Illustrator so that when they appear in InDesign, they are text boxes rather than image boxes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are your InDesign Display Performance Settings?

Comment: Ah, it was in typical display. Changed it to high display and it worked. Though will it print in high quality, I'm still wondering ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your **InDesign Display Performance Settings**.

What you show is generally the result of the "typical" setting.

Note these are **display** performance settings and only effect how placed images appear in InDesign. Everything always prints at "high" quality regardless of the display settings.